# Regex on htaccess file gives INTERNAL REDIRECT error

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, pcre, internal-server-error

I'm trying to create a redirect rule that matches the following urls:

```
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-9/
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/9/
en/property/rotterdam-centrum/appartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/9
en/property/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-9/
en/property/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v9/
en/property/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-9/
en/property/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-9
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/branch/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-9/
en/property/rotterdam/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-9/
en/property/rotterdam/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-9434343/
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-243249/
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v2342349/
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/243249/
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-9/
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-9/?test=1
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-9/test/one/?success=3
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/2-rooms/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-9/blah/1234/blahh/55555/?sass=123
en/property/rotterdam/appartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/9234234
en/property/rotterdam/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/9234234
en/property/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/9234234
en/property/9234234
en/property/rotterdam/appartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/9/test/132?algo=123
```

All urls that need to be match can be seen here
https://regex101.com/r/4TPEhy/1

I'm facing **two issues**, **first one** is that two urls are not matching:

```
en/property/rotterdam/apartment/2-rooms/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-9/blah/1234/blahh/55555/?sass=123
en/property/9234234
```

And the second one, something on that regex is causing an interal redirect error.

This is my regex (the best case that I got so far)

```
^(en\/)?property\/[A-Яa-я0-9\-_\/]+?([\d]+)(.*)$
```

And this is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(en\/)?property\/[A-Яa-я0-9\-_\/]+?([\d]+)(.*)$ $1properties/property/$2$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

The regex seems to be working fine on the tool (regex101), but as soon as a try to refresh the page applying that rule I get a **500 - Internal Server Error**.

I need to match all the cases, I've tried different combinations for hours, but I'm missing something that's causing those issues.

On the .htaccess the groups that I need are $2 and $3, since $2 contains the property ID which I'm using on my script and $3 is all the rest of the URL like any other extra parameter or the query string.

The reason for so many different configurations is that users can set their own URL format, but limited to the options listed above.

This is an extract from the apache logs when this URL is requested

```
https://localhost/en/property/rotterdam/apartment/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v-9/test/132?blah=123
```

**Logs**

```
php74         | [Mon May 31 12:19:12.375537 2021] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 64] mod_rewrite.c(483): [client 172.18.0.1:63664] 172.18.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7fd3d4ab1958][rid#7fd3d29d73c0/initial/redir#10] [perdir /var/www/html/] add per-dir prefix: en/properties/property/9/test/132&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123 -> /var/www/html/en/properties/property/9/test/132&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123&blah=123
```

Comment: If URL is `/en/property/lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/v9/` then what should be captured in `$2` and `$3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this rewrite rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en/)?property/(?:\S*?[-/v])?(\d+)(/.*)?$ $1properties/property/$2$3 [NC,L]
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4TPEhy/2)

We are capturing property ID after a `-` or `/` or `v` characters.

Comment: thanks! this was really helpful :) I'm still missing why I was getting the internal redirect error with the previous rule. The only thing I can think of is that the regex had more than one match